# How can I write a big set in overleaf

Tags: amsmath, overleaf

I want to write a set with 14 elements, for that I am using this but this keeps it all in one line and half of the set is visible only

```
$$S=\Bigg\{(0,0,2),(0,0,-2),(2^*,1,1^*),(2^*,-1,-1^*),(0^*,1,-1^*),(0^*,-1,1^*),(0^*,-1,-1^*)\\
(1,2^*,0^*),(-1,2^*,0^*),(1,0^*,-2^*),(-1,0^*,2^*),(1,0^*,0^*),(-1,0^*,0^*)\Bigg\}$$
```

See the image below-

[image]

What can I do to make set with in page?

Answer (score 3):

use of $$ for displayed equations is deprecated. Instead it rather use `\[ ...\]`. In your case, this will not breake your set into two lines. For this you need some math environment from`asmath` package or use `tabular` or `array`environment.

Since you didn't provide MWE, I wrote one for you:

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=3mm,preview]{standalone}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

        \begin{document}
The examined set has \dots elements:
    \begin{multline}\label{eq:set-1}
S=\Bigl\{(0,0,2), (0,0,-2), (2^*,1,1^*), (2^*,-1,-1^*),(0^*,1,-1^*),\\
         (0^*,-1,1^*), (0^*,-1,-1^*), (1,2^*,0^*),(-1,2^*,0^*),\\
         (1,0^*,-2^*),(-1,0^*,2^*),(1,0^*,0^*),(-1,0^*,0^*)\Bigr\}
     \end{multline}
From \eqref{eq:set-1} we can see \dots 
    \end{document}
```

It gives the following result:

[image]

Comment: it says "\begin{multline} allowed only in paragr aph mode." I dont know what to do. I am typing project report.

Comment: Who this say? I newer hear this. `multline` is macro for displayed math like `{qgin{equation} ... \end{equation}` or `\begin{gather} ... \end{gather}` and so on.

Comment: is there any other way, please tell me. I am stuck on this set.

Comment: What is wrong with proposed solution? If you like to have your set in more lines, just broke line with one more `\\` in appropriate place in set. You should privide more data, I can only guess what you like to obtain.

Comment: multline is not working. And also inside `\[\]` `\\` is not braeking lines

Comment: `\[ ... \]` is for one-line equations.  it will never break the line.  i have no idea why `\begin{multline} ...` is not working; perhaps you have loaded another package (besides `amsmath`) that redefines it -- you haven't provided enough information for diagnosis.

Comment: Then you have somewhere an error. Proposed solution work for sure (tested). Please, provide minimal working example,  without it I can't help you.

Comment: its fine, as \\ worked under `\(\)`, but wasnt working in `\[\]`. Thanks

Comment: Show this with own MWE.

Comment: It works fine in TexMaker, but is it possible that all three rows inside braces are aligned, and the left right braces covers full side of all three equations

Comment: From math point of view this is not very good idea. But if you persist, you can achieve this on more ways: by  `\begin{Bmatrix} ... \end{Bmatrix} (frome `amsmath` package) or by `\left\{\begin{tabular}{l} ... \end{tabular}\right\}` etc. I strongly encourage you to read amsmath package documentation or https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics or some other basic literature about math in LateX.